# How to add defaults to existing columns with Gorm

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

I'm using gorm and have a model like so:

```
type MyModel struct {
    CreationTime      time.Time 
    UpdateTime        time.Time
}
```

I realized after deploying my DB that creation time and update time weren't adding times when items were being created and updated! I tried to fix this by updating the model to the following:

```
type MyModel struct {
    CreationTime      time.Time       `gorm:"default:current_timestamp"`
    UpdateTime        time.Time       `gorm:"default:current_timestamp ON update current_timestamp"`
}
```

However, auto migrating like the following won't apply these defaults on the already existing tables!

```
 db.AutoMigrate(&MyModel{})
```

Is there any way I can use the built in migration functions to add defaults to columns? I searched the docs and it seems like I can only change the type of existing columns! If not, any recommendations for a why to simply add defaults to a column via migrations?

Comment: What is the version of gorm you are using? Is it v1? And do you need to solve this only for postgres?

Comment: Hi! I'm using gorm 1.9 and yup! Only for postgres!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `sql` tag?

```
`sql:"DEFAULT:current_timestamp"`
```

Comment: `Automigrate()` of gorm doesn't change a column's default. If it were to create a new table, then yes this would work.

Answer (score 0):

The automigration provided by gorm doesn't delete or modify your columns and for good reasons, it's not safe.
I had a similar issue. I needed to drop the null constraint from one of my columns and couldn't find anything that does that in gorm, and I'm pretty sure it doesn't. I wrote my own function for doing this. You can easily do something similar.

Please take a look at these two commits: [this](https://github.com/vabshere/gorm/commit/c9d8908b62e4575a33ab309226af931ab9f7e877) and [this](https://github.com/vabshere/gorm/commit/a2832f157a1353ab4baa75d25f8a161e04dd022c). What you can basically do this is to define a method for the `Dialect` interface and then write an implementation for that method for the `commonDialect` type (and the `postgres` type, if required).

Hope this helps. Feel free to ask me if you face any problems with implementation or have any doubts.

Answer (score -1):

You can try

> gorm:"autoUpdateTime:milli"